# Taking input from a text file for implementing Caesar Cipher

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I am trying to implement Caesar cipher in Python where my program would take input from a text file i.e. `input_file.txt`, and write the encrypted text as an output to another text file named `output_file.txt`. The input file contains:

> ```
> Attack On Titans
> 4
> ```

where `"Attack On Titan"` is the string to be encrypted and `4` is the key to the encryption algorithm. The correct output for this string should be

> ```
> Exxego Sr Xmxerw
> ```

but my program gives me

> ```
> Exxego Sr Xmxerwv
> ```

***i.e an extra character v***. Here is my code for review:

```
data = open("input_file.txt", "r")
text = data.readline()
print(text)
key = int(data.readline())

def encrypt(text,key):
 result = ""
 for i in range(len(text)):
    char = text[i]
    if char == ' ':
        result += ' '
    elif char.isupper():
        result += chr((ord(char) + key-65) % 26 + 65)
    else:
        result += chr((ord(char) + key - 97) % 26 + 97)
 return result

ex= open("output_file.txt","w")
ex.write(encrypt(text,key))
print(encrypt(text , key))
```

I just wanted to know why am I getting this incorrect output although I know I can make it correct if I change the for statement by doing this:

```
for i in range(len(text)-1)
```

Please don't mind this amateurish coding since I am not good at it and want to improve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`data.readline()` will give you the trailing newline character `\n`. You need to call `text.strip()` before passing to the `encrypt` function to get arid of it.

Answer (score 1):

It look like you have a trailing newline character in the file you are reading in.

Testing it in the python interpreter:

```
>>> a = '\n'
>>> (ord(a)+4-97) % 26 + 97
118
>>> chr(118)
'v'
```

Remove trailing and beginning whitespace by calling `test.strip()` before passing it to your encrypt function.

As an aside, you should either explicitly close your files, e.g. `ex.close()` or wrap in in a block like this, to prevent file corruption.

```
with open('', 'r') as ex:
    ex.write('bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

data.readline() keeps the '\n' (newline) character at the end of the line. It's the reason why you have an extra character in your output.

To remove it you can replace

```
text = data.readline()
```

by

```
text = data.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

which will remove the '\n' at the end.

text.strip() (see other answers) will remove all [whitespace characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.whitespace) from both end of the string. So if it's not the behaviour expected, use .rstrip('\n') which removes only '\n' at the end of the string.

You should also add

```
ex.close()
```

after

```
ex.write(encrypt(text,key))
```

to commit the change to the file.